# Expression including permutations of $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$ $\mod p$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p>3$ be prime. Given the number $k \not\equiv 1 (\mod p)$ and lettting  $\{ \sigma_{0},\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{p-1}\}$ be permutation of $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$ decide whether $$A=\sigma_{0}+k \cdot \sigma_{1}+k^{2} \cdot \sigma_{2}+...+ k^{p-1} \cdot \sigma_{p-1} \equiv 0 (\mod p)$$  holds for $(p-1)!$ permutations.
Using computer I have already checked that it's true for $p=5,7,11,13$.   Additionaly  I proved that $A \equiv 1,2,...,p-1  ( \mod p )$ have same amount of permutations that satisfy it (I showed bijection) however my proof doesn't show that there are $(p-1)!$ of them.

Comment: I'm sorry I might have written it in confusing way. Maybe I should give an example. Take $p=5$ and $k=2$ then we have $A= \sigma_{0}+2\sigma_{1}+4\sigma_{2}+8\sigma_{3}+16\sigma_{4}$ If we take $\sigma_{0}=1, \sigma_{1}=4, \sigma_{2}=0, \sigma_{3}=3, \sigma_{4}=2$ we get $A \equiv 0 (\mod p)$. My guess is that there are $(p-1)!$ permutations of $\sigma$ such that $A \equiv 0$, $A\equiv 1$, ..., $A \equiv p-1$ $(\mod p)$ however I am unable to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy if you noticed the sum of coefficients $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}k^i=\frac{k^p-1}{k-1}\equiv 1\mod p$. Let $A(\sigma_0,\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_{p-1})=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\sigma_ik^i\mod p$. So we consider grouping the permutations like $(\sigma_0+j,\sigma_1+j,\dots,\sigma_{p-1}+j)$ for $j=0,1,\dots,p-1$, $p$ permutations in a group. Then we can get $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}(\sigma_i+j)k^i\equiv j+\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\sigma_ik^i\mod p$. So in this group, all the residue will be appeared in some $A(\sigma_0+j,\sigma_1+j,\dots,\sigma_{p-1}+j)$ exactly once. This implies the number of $A$ in all the residue classes are all the same.